# GROBID Python client in Docker: How do I resolve './config.json' not found error?

Tags: python, docker, command-line, client, grobid

I am trying to use GROBID installed via Docker to convert PDFs into XML files. I am using the guide from https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid_client_python.

After writing this code in the WSL command prompt (with my proper directories):

```
grobid_client --input ~/tmp/in2 --output ~/tmp/out processFulltextDocument
```

I get an error of:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './config.json'
```

Full error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS1dT.png)

I am confused about whether I should have created a config.json file; or, if it was already supposed to be there, why the command prompt is saying there is no file like that.
I have tried checking the file path of the WSL command prompt to see if there is a config.json file there, but the computer will not let me open the folder with this error:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/myecN.png)

How do I fix this issue and get the code to work in the WSL command prompt? I am new to this so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `--config /path/to/config_file`.

You could create the config file directly in the WSL and copy-paste it from github

https://github.com/kermitt2/grobid_client_python/blob/master/config.json